# Where is C-3P0 during the events of aftermath?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-aftermath

Where is C-3P0 during the events of Aftermath? Is he with Luke?

I don't remember anything being mentioned in the previous novels, and he is present in *Bloodlines* as Leia's assistant.

Comment: He is in the canon comic "Shattered Empire" which is post-Endor and prior to "Bloodlines"